# One-Click Script to Gmail Yourself a File

Tags: shell, scripting, email

Does such a thing exist?  I'd be interested in something like:

1. You right-click a file in a file viewing manager, and click "gmail yourself this file".  One click, and you're done.
2. You open up the command-line, and type something like `gmail ~/file.txt` and `file.txt` is instantly sent to your own account.

Comment: For #1, I would rather use dropbox, most systems provides the feature to move file to dropbox on rightclick. For #2, you can easily write a one-liner using mutt, see: http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples

Comment: Not where I can write an answer but you can [use this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MuttAndGmail) to set up `mutt` to work with gmail after which `echo email body | mutt address@gmail.com -a /etc/fstab` should send you an email with `/etc/fstab` as a MIME (not uuencode) attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this one is not exactly the way you want. But still it could be useful for the second option in your question.

Install the required packages.

```
sudo apt-get install msmtp-mta
```

Edit the following file to add the details. If the file doesn't exist, you could create it.

```
vi ~/.msmtprc

#Gmail account
defaults
logfile ~/msmtp.log

account gmail
auth on
host smtp.gmail.com
from your_address@gmail.com
auth on
tls on
tls_trust_file /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Equifax_Secure_CA.crt
user your_address@gmail.com
password your_gmail_password
port 587
```

account default : gmail

Change the permissions of the above file so that others couldn't read your user account details.

```
chmod 600 .msmtprc
```

Now, install a command line email program to write your email.

```
sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx
```

Now, again edit/create the below file.

```
vi ~/.mailrc
```

Add the below entries to the above file.

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set message-sendmail-extra-arguments="-a gmail"
```

We are done to send email from the command line.

**Testing**

```
mail -a hello.txt -s "CHECKING" recipient-mail-id
ENTER THE MAIL CONTENTS HERE.
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>d</kbd> to finish the mail contents.

**References**

http://tuxtweaks.com/2012/10/send-gmail-from-the-linux-command-line/